# Preventing Data Tampering in HTTPS Requests: Safeguarding User-Initiated Donations

Tags: javascript, django, https, request, fetch

Could a Man-in-the-Middle (MITM) attack compromise the integrity of user-initiated transactions over HTTPS? Specifically, if a user selects an amount to donate on a website, is it possible for a hacker to intercept and modify the donation amount?If yes, what strategies can be implemented to safeguard against unauthorized alterations and ensure the security of transactions conducted over HTTPS?

note: I'm using django in development.

Comment: This is less of a programming question and more of a security question. It is more suitable for [security.se] (Check for duplicates before posting)